# Make onclick location.href work in echo php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am really stumped on this. I can not get it to work. It seems that there is something wrong with my syntax. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<?php
    echo '<tr onClick="location.href="http://executivevalet.net.au/app/calendar.php?action=display_event&oid='.$eid[$a].'""><td>Link</link</tr>
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use escape quotes using `\`
Backslashes are used in PHP to escape special characters within quotes. As PHP does not distinguish between strings and characters

try this:

```
echo "<tr onClick='location.href=\"http://executivevalet.net.au/app/calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=".$eid[$a]."\"'><td>".$date[$a]."</td><td>".$eid[$a]."</td><td>".$subject[$a]."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: glad to help you :) @user2374173 remind to accept the answer when you can to help other guys with your same problem

Answer (score 3):

Escape your double quotes with a backslash (or PHP interprets it as the end of a string)!

```
$a=0;
while(mysql_num_rows($result)>$a){
    echo "<tr onClick=\"location.href='http://executivevalet.net.au/app/calendar.php?action=display_event&oid=<?php echo $eid[$a]; ?>'\"><td>".$date[$a]."</td><td>".$eid[$a]."</td><td>".$subject[$a]."</td></tr>";
$a++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As both Cagy79 and Alessandro Minoccheri have said - your PHP syntax is wrong.

You should be getting errors in your web server logs, and you can always check your syntax using PHP on the command line (if applicable): "`php -l <filename>.php`"

The error will be something like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in test.php on line 8
Errors parsing test.php
```

It's telling you that there was an unexpected string (textual data) on line 8.  It was expecting either a comma or semi-colon.  This is logical, as echo could take a comma to separate arguments - and the semi-colon would complete the line.

Either of the proposed solutions from the above people will fix your issue.